# cygwin,how to set BASE_PATH in .sh file?

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I set BASE_PATH in .sh file like this:

```
BASE_PATH="D:/Program files/VisualSFM/Bundler";
```

And,I used cygwin to run the .sh file, but got some errors:

./RunBundler.sh:line56:D:/Program:No such file or directory.

I have tried many ways to solve the problem,and i found that if the file name(BASE_PATH) contains space,the cygwin can not find the file or directory.So how to set BASE_PATH in .sh file if the BASE_PATH contains space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this path:

```
BASE_PATH="/cygdrive/D/Program files/VisualSFM/Bundler"
```

OR

```
BASE_PATH="/cygdrive/D/Progra~1/VisualSFM/Bundler"
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. Please consider accepting the answer now.